# How to route requests to a method in a class in WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In MVC one can write a custom route that points to a method on a controller, i would like to achieve the same functionality with WebForms.

If i have a route like;

```
Admin/{Controller}/{Action}
```

I would like to user a Url like the one below to invoke the Register method on a User class/controller.

```
http://[domain]/Admin/User/Register
```

How do i go about doing something like this.

**NOTE**

I've found an answer to my question elsewhere;
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Mar/28/Custom-ASPNET-Routing-to-an-HttpHandler

Basically, i am using WebForms to develop an app, however wanted the controller concept of the MVC - the ability to execute methods that exist on a controller. I've been able to achieve my goal, thanks to that article.

Comment: Here is an article on this topic http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_ASP.NET_Web_Services—Invoking_the_Web_Metho

Comment: I don't see anything about invoking the service dynamically

Comment: make a webservice and migrate your hello to this service.. only then you can call dynamically and use json type service

Comment: I think maybe you're looking for ASP.Net Ajax "Page methods"?  There's plenty of info on this topic, see here for example: http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/exposingwebservicestoajaxtutorial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All WebMethod's on a page must be declared as `static`, and a User.aspx has a class in your application, so anywhere in your code you can call `User.Hello()`

What you want to do is better served with a WebService, however I don't see anything technically limiting you from doing it this way.